# Customer Email Address

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

Here is my issue: A customer used the wrong suffix in his email address and I would like to correct his order record for order notes.

Is this possible to edit? Using woocommerce.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother anyone. There is an edit pencil that now appears on the order page. It wasn't showing when I asked. Thanks for your time. I'm a dinghy!

Comment: is you have access to your DB anything is possible